# How to mark all my sms messages as unread?

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I know how to loop over the sms messages but I do not know how to update the status of the message.

```
            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
            String sms = "";
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                 //iterating throught all the messages
            }
```

Comment: Good question. There does exist a `SmsManager.getStatusOnIcc`, but there is no corresponding setter. In fact, everything about an SMS is read-only. All you can do is send an SMS using this class. - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#getStatusOnIcc()

Answer (score 0):

The CyanogenMod Mms app has a "Mark All As Read" feature. Changing things up to mark everything as unread shouldn't be too much trouble. https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Mms/blob/ics/src/com/android/mms/data/Conversation.java#L916

Comment: I need this for both sense and cyanoge mode , :(